# How I get data from json with linq?

Tags: c#, json, linq

```
[
  {
    "id": "133",
    "label": "S/M",
    "price": "0",
    "oldPrice": "0",
    "products": [
      "318",
      "321",
      "324",
      "327"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "132",
    "label": "L/XL",
    "price": "0",
    "oldPrice": "0",
    "products": [
      "319",
      "322",
      "325",
      "328"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "131",
    "label": "XXL/XXXL",
    "price": "0",
    "oldPrice": "0",
    "products": [
      "320",
      "323",
      "326",
      "329"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get 'label' where array "products" contains "321". How i can make this?  I used library json.net

```
i make linq expression 
JArray ja = JArray("this json");
JValue id = JValue.Parse("328");
ja.Select(x => x["label"]).Where(x => x["products"].Contains(id));
```

But i get "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."

Comment: Have you tried using a JSON deserializer such as JSON.NET?

Answer (score 1):

So you should define the class first:

```
class MyObj {
public string id { get; set; }
public string[] products { get; set; }
public string label { get; set; }

}
```

And deserialize that instead of object:

```
 var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize<MyObj>(str);
 var result =  deserialized.Where(r => r.products.Contains("321")).ToList();
```

Comment: `serializer.Deserialize<MyObj>(str);` this won't work, OP has an array of items

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a library like [JSON.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/).
In this case you can write something like this

```
string json = <your json string>;
var deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json).Where(p => p.products.Contains("321")).ToList();
```

where Product is

```
public class Product
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string[] products { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use any JSON library. e.g. [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

This [LINQ to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) sample

Comment: I used this library. But i cant make correct linq expression.